# Bike makes noise while 2 out of 3 gears

Tags: brakes, wheels, gears, noise, new-bicycle-assembly

I assembled a new bike. It rides smooth in first gear but makes a particular noise in 2nd and 3rd gear. It doesn't seem to be from the wheel because it's not there if I turn the wheels in air, but it is when I am riding the bike.

This is a new bike that I assembled. It has disk brakes if that matters and total 3 gears.

What could this be?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycle Stack Exchange. For clarity, and to generate better--or any--answers, some more information would be helpful. Stuff like make/model of the bike, whether it has a derailleur and multiple sprockets or is it an internally geared hub?  You may edit your question with additional information at any time.

Comment: By 3 gears do you mean 3 chain rings in the front? A video recording would be really helpful.

Comment: I am assuming you have an internally geared hub. I would check the chain tension (if it's excessive it can cause noises) and wheel alignment (make sure the rear sprocket is properly aligned with the chain)